# How do I create an Iteratee in akka?

Tags: scala, akka

I have a library that was written in Java that's essentially a pub/sub style queue. The interface is roughly:

```
class Queue(subscriber: Thing => ()) {
  def publish(thing: Thing) {
  }
}
```

How do I create an Akka Iteratee that represents the events from a subscriber? i.e. Each time the subscriber function is called, I want the Iteratee object to provide another element.

Comment: Could you describe the problem in more detail? Usually iteratees are used to process data in a single thread, but if you want to receive some events, it seems that you'll have two. Then it'd be better to use actors to just pass messages.

Comment: I do not see how this question is related to Akka, which Iteratees do you mean?